# Merge array of objects by nested property ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

This is my example:

```
{
    id: 'productId',
    label: 'productLabel',
    items: productSizes.map( productSize => {
        return {
            id: productSize.groupId,
            label: productSize.groupId.split('-')[0],
            items: productSize.size,
        }
    }),
}
```

This would result in something like this with our data:

```
{
    id: 'productId',
    label: 'productLabel'
    items: [
        {id: 'productA-11', label: 'productA', items: {width: 100, height: 100}},
        {id: 'productA-11', label: 'productA', items: {width: 150, height: 150}},
        {id: 'productA-11', label: 'productA', items: {width: 200, height: 200}},
        {id: 'productB-22', label: 'productB', items: {width: 100, height: 100}},
    ]
}
```

But I would like to get something like this:

```
{
    id: 'productId',
    label: 'productLabel'
    items: [
        {id: 'productA-11', label: 'productA', items: [ {width: 100, height: 100}, {width: 150, height: 150}, {width: 200, height:200}],
        {id: 'productB-22', label: 'productB', items: [{width: 100, height: 100}],
    ]
}
```

Not sure if I described my problem well with words, but I would like to somehow flatten the inner property `items`, so that sizes of the SAME `productId` would be merged into a single array.

Comment: What have you attempted to merge them so far? Where are you stuck with? Please post the code that you have attempted, so that someone can check and help you to solve the issue.

Comment: @Nitheesh I have no code as I have no clue how to start with tackling this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.reduce` will help you

**Logic**

- Loop throughthe `items` array of your object.
- Check if the accumulator of the reducer already have an item with same `id` and `label`
- It there is a node with same `id` and `label`, push the current item to the `items` array of that node else insert a new node to the accumulator with `id`, `label` and `items`

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const data = {
  id: 'productId',
  label: 'productLabel',
  items: [
    { id: 'productA-11', label: 'productA', items: { width: 100, height: 100 } },
    { id: 'productA-11', label: 'productA', items: { width: 150, height: 150 } },
    { id: 'productA-11', label: 'productA', items: { width: 200, height: 200 } },
    { id: 'productB-22', label: 'productB', items: { width: 100, height: 100 } },
  ]
};
const { id, label } = data;
const items = data.items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const node = acc.find(item => item.id === curr.id && item.label === curr.label);
  if (node) {
    node.items.push(curr.items);
  } else {
    acc.push({
      id: curr.id,
      label: curr.label,
      items: [curr.items]
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, [])
const output = {
  id,
  label,
  items,
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you Nitheesh, it works. I thought about array.reduce(), but never understood it really well.